# How to get the similar-sounding words together

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to get all the similar sounding words from a list.

I tried to get them using cosine similarity but that does not fulfil my purpose.

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
dataList = ['two','fourth','forth','dessert','to','desert']
cosine_similarity(dataList)
```

I know this is not the right approach, I cannot seem to get a result like:

```
result = ['xx', 'xx', 'yy', 'yy', 'zz', 'zz']
```

where they mean that the words which sound similar

Answer (score 34, accepted):

First, you need to use a right way to get the similar sounding words i.e. *string similarity*, I would suggest:

Using [`jellyfish`](https://github.com/jamesturk/jellyfish):

```
from jellyfish import soundex

print(soundex("two"))
print(soundex("to"))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
T000
T000
```

Now perhaps, create a function that would handle the list and then sort it to get them:

```
def getSoundexList(dList):
    res = [soundex(x) for x in dList]   # iterate over each elem in the dataList
    # print(res)     # ['T000', 'F630', 'F630', 'D263', 'T000', 'D263']
    return res

dataList = ['two','fourth','forth','dessert','to','desert']    
print([x for x in sorted(getSoundexList(dataList))])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
['D263', 'D263', 'F630', 'F630', 'T000', 'T000']
```

**EDIT**:

Another way could be:

Using [`fuzzy`](https://pypi.org/project/Fuzzy/):

```
import fuzzy
soundex = fuzzy.Soundex(4)

print(soundex("to"))
print(soundex("two"))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
T000
T000
```

**EDIT 2**:

If you want them `grouped`, you could use groupby:

```
from itertools import groupby

def getSoundexList(dList):
    return sorted([soundex(x) for x in dList])

dataList = ['two','fourth','forth','dessert','to','desert']    
print([list(g) for _, g in groupby(getSoundexList(dataList), lambda x: x)])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[['D263', 'D263'], ['F630', 'F630'], ['T000', 'T000']]
```

**EDIT 3**:

This ones for @Eric Duminil, let's say you want both the `names` and their respective `val`:

Using a `dict` along with [`itemgetter`](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/841/operator.itemgetter):

```
from operator import itemgetter

def getSoundexDict(dList):
    return sorted(dict_.items(), key=itemgetter(1))  # sorting the dict_ on val

dataList = ['two','fourth','forth','dessert','to','desert']
res = [soundex(x) for x in dataList]    # to get the val for each elem
dict_ = dict(list(zip(dataList, res)))  # dict_ with k,v as name/val

print([list(g) for _, g in groupby(getSoundexDict(dataList), lambda x: x[1])])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[[('dessert', 'D263'), ('desert', 'D263')], [('fourth', 'F630'), ('forth', 'F630')], [('two', 'T000'), ('to', 'T000')]]
```

**EDIT 4** (for OP):

**Soundex:**

> Soundex is a system whereby values are assigned to names in such a
>   manner that similar-sounding names get the same value.  These values
>   are known as soundex encodings.  A search application based on soundex
>   will not search for a name directly but rather will search for the
>   soundex encoding.  By doing so, it will obtain all names that sound
>   like the name being sought.

[read more..](https://stevemorse.org/phonetics/bmpm2.htm)

Comment: Here another case that is similar to the above, and actually inspired in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66716881/7127519 and perhaps interesting : )