# String Comparison in Python for harmonization

Tags: python

I am coming from SQL world and we are using pandas for ETL this time. We use DIFFERENCE and SOUNDEX for the string comparison. But its not giving expected results lately. Is there any way to achieve this in python?

Currently we are using code like below which will return a score for the match.

```
SELECT difference(soundex('string'),soundex(Col)) from table
```

Looking for a similar solution here. Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you show an example ? Like two strings, and the expected result of your function ?

Comment: Soundex is available for Python but it has significant shortcomings, as is shown by the numerous attempts at improving it. And to be fair, it was designed for rapid computation by human beings, and with American surnames primarily in mind. The only reason it is still popular is because it is provided by many dialects of SQL. Consider filtering your data in SQL by selecting on the first letter (which matches what Soundex does) and doing the similarity filtering afterwards in Python using Metaphone https://pypi.org/project/Metaphone/ or Levenshtein https://pypi.org/project/python-Levenshtein/ .

Comment: If your question is "could this be done?" then the answer will most probably be a "yes". If you need help writing the code for it, you would need to be more specific. what did you try so far? what issues did you encounter?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66715423/distance-between-strings-by-similarity-of-sound/66716881#66716881  try from jellyfish import soundex