# How do I figure out which word sounds most similar to a given word?

Tags: python, nlp, levenshtein-distance, soundex

so I have been using Levenshtein distance to calculate the difference between my words and a generated new word, like so:
`-1*np.array([distance.levenshtein(word_use,w2) for w2 in words])`

Then I do other stuff with the result. I wish to produce a similar result, but for the way the words sound. This is proving really difficult.

ChatGPT advised me about jellyfish's match_rating_index, but this only accepts one string and I don't really see the utility of it for my purposes since it just outputs some weird string on its own, and then to use "ord" on it, and then I guess do the numerical comparison. I don't see this working the way I want it to.

Any humans have any better ideas? I am fully aware of the "different regions pronounce things differently" problem. This is irrelevant to my purpose.

EDIT:
I've seen soundex: [How to get the similar-sounding words together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55331723/how-to-get-the-similar-sounding-words-together)

But it just outputs codes. If I have a hundred words in a list, and I need to figure out which one a new word sounds most like, and we exclude the simple case of "these two output the same code," then soundex looks pretty useless for my case.

EDIT 2:
The link (frankly, lazily) given to close my question doesn't help me. Levenshtein of soundex codes is absolutely no better than Levenshtein of the words themselves. It just adds a level of arbitrary complexity, and further, the way Levenshtein works to compare strings means that codes, despite being say T000->D263 and M116->D263 yield 4 and 4, respectively, which does not help me - this is very arbitrary closeness and doesn't take into account sound. Levenshtein distance between phonemic representations would never work for me  because I care that /s/ and /z/ are closer to each other than they are to /k/.

Comment: Levenshtein distance is for spelling, not pronunciation. Look up "soundex".

Comment: I've seen this, but it outputs codes that are irreducible to (non-arbitrary) numbers as far as I can tell, so I can't compare options to the new word to see which is the closest, I don't think.

Comment: *"Levenshtein of soundex codes is absolutely no better than Levenshtein of the words themselves."* How about Levenshtein of metaphone or nysiis codes, as suggested in the top answer to the linked question? They look as if they would be more meaningful than Soundex.

Comment: Stepping back, is it that the phonemic representations available aren't good enough, or is that Levenshtein distance between phonemic representations would never work for you? (e.g. because you care that /s/ and /z/ are closer to each other than they are to /k/ ?)

Comment: The latter, it matters that /s/ and /z/ are closer to one another than to /k/.

Comment: Right: so this gets into concepts like "phonological edit distance" where changes between strings are "weighted according to featural similarity". See: https://corpustools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/string_similarity.html#phonological-edit-distance. The person in this answer - https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/20007 - wrote some Python code using that package, so that kind of thing might be a way forward.

Comment: Awesome, I'll take a look at those resources. They look promising already at a glance. Thanks a ton!