# Pandas Groupby but within % match instead of exact match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a 400k row dataframe with a column of strings that I would like to groupby if they are similar to within 90% and not just an exact match due to spelling errors etc.  I've tried rapidfuzz but am still struggling to find a solution that doesn't take ages.

So far I've only used the standard Pandas.groupby but there are still some that are very close but don't group because they are not exact.  I've also tried running a loop of each value against all the other values but that takes hours and hours.  I've used fuzz QRatio and SequenceMatcher to find the match ratio but haven't been able to scale it to the hundreds of thousands of rows.

Example data:

`data = pd.DataFrame(data=["Apple", "Apple", "apple", "appel", "aple", "Orange", "Banana"],columns=["Fruits"], dtype="str")`

Desired Outcome:
As for name of the 'category' either the most used value or just the first instance of it is fine.

| Fruit | Occurs |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 5 |
| Orange | 1 |
| Banana | 1 |

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Part of the problem is that you can get chains of similar worlds. You might allow Aple to be deemed similar to Apel, but then that's similar to Ape (even though Ape and Aple wouldn't be similar, they're linked through Apel). Essentially you get a Web of associations. The other way of looking at it is Clustering. Using fuzzy matching or some distance calculation, you can cluster similar words, and then tune where the clustering boundaries are. In short, it's perfectly possible, but certainly non-trivial.

Comment: That kind of issue is difficult to troubleshoot without the real dataset. For instance if you have a word that is close to two possibilities, what should you do?

Comment: I also recommend looking into soundex algorithms. As long as the typos don't fundamentally change the sounds of the words, that may group similar words well enough for you; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55331723/how-to-get-the-similar-sounding-words-together

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Levenshtein Distance**: Levenshtein distance is a measure of the similarity between two strings, which takes into account the number of insertion, deletion and substitution operations needed to transform one string into the other.
As explained here
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/introduction-to-levenshtein-distance/

Building on the levenshteinRecursive function there spesific to your case:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict
data = pd.DataFrame(data=["Apple", "Apple", "apple", "appel", "aple", "Orange", "Banana"],columns=["Fruits"], dtype="str")

def levenshteinRecursive(str1, str2, m, n):
      # str1 is empty
    if m == 0:
        return n
    # str2 is empty
    if n == 0:
        return m
    if str1[m - 1] == str2[n - 1]:
        return levenshteinRecursive(str1, str2, m - 1, n - 1)
    return 1 + min(
          # Insert     
        levenshteinRecursive(str1, str2, m, n - 1),
        min(
              # Remove
            levenshteinRecursive(str1, str2, m - 1, n),
          # Replace
            levenshteinRecursive(str1, str2, m - 1, n - 1))
    )

def group_similar_strings(data, threshold=4):
    categories = {}

    for index, row in data.iterrows():
        matched = False

        for category in categories:
            if levenshteinRecursive(row["Fruits"], category, len(row["Fruits"]), len(category)) <= threshold:
                categories[category].append(row["Fruits"])
                matched = True
                break

        if not matched:
            categories[row["Fruits"]] = [row["Fruits"]]

    occurrences = {category: len(values) for category, values in categories.items()}
    
    return occurrences

result = group_similar_strings(data)
result = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(result, orient="index", columns=["Occurs"]).reset_index().rename(columns={"index": "Fruit"})

print(result)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use `rapidfuzz`, a derived version of `fuzzywuzzy` that should be faster:

`pip install rapidfuzz`

Then you could create a column that hase the ratio necessary to performe the groupby:

### Define the function and threshold of similarity

```
def find_similar_strings(string, strings, threshold=90):
    ratios = []
    for s in strings:
        ratio = fuzz.ratio(string, s)
        if ratio <= threshold:
            ratios.append(ratio)
        else:
            ratios.append(100)

    return ratios
```

### Apply fuzzy matching ratio as a column

```
data['Fuzz Ratio'] = data['Fruits'].apply(lambda x: find_similar_strings(x, data['Fruits']))
```

Finally, you can groupby all the observation that has score of similarity == 100 (based on the threshold you previously set):

```
data[data['Fuzz Ratio'] == 100].groupby('Fruits').size().reset_index(name='Occurs')
```